# From where i can download Apache CXF tools

Tags: apache, cxf, soapui

I want to generate code using apache cxf tools but was not able to find a download link for it. On web-page http://cxf.apache.org/docs/tools.html there is no link to download tools package. I need this tools to use with SoapUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://cxf.apache.org/download.html) is the high-level download page for the various versions that are currently available from Apache; version 2.7.7 is the most recent (at this time) and the binary files are available as;

- apache-cxf-2.7.7.zip (Windows)
- apache-cxf-2.7.7.tar.gz (*nix)

Comment: this download packages only contains compiled classes but no tools.

Comment: Sorry. It has the tools (they're scripts) in the bin folder in the zip (or tar.gz) files.

Comment: Try tar tvvf apache-cxf-2.7.7.tar.gz | grep bin\/ | awk '{print $6}'

Answer (score 0):

it should be available on this page

http://cxf.apache.org/download.html